# CircleCI Angular ng build - Allocation Failure (Memory issue)?

Tags: node.js, angular, memory, circleci, circleci-2.0

We've been running our builds on circleci for a while. Recently (sometimes) they fail because of allocation failure when running `ng build`.

The specific build command we are using is

```
ng build --prod --sourcemaps --aot true --build-optimizer --env=stage
```

This is the output log.

```
70% building modules 1562/1562 modules 0 active
79% module and chunk tree optimization         
80% chunk modules optimization
81% advanced chunk modules optimization                     
82% module reviving
83% module order optimization   
84% module id optimization
85% chunk reviving
86% chunk order optimization    
87% chunk id optimization
88% hashing
89% module assets processing
90% chunk assets processing
91% additional chunk assets processing
92% recording 91% additional asset processing   
92% chunk asset optimization
<--- Last few GCs --->

121548 ms: Scavenge 1327.9 (1434.3) -> 1327.8 (1434.3) MB, 21.8 / 0 ms (+ 1.6 ms in 9 steps since last GC) [allocation failure].
121572 ms: Scavenge 1327.9 (1434.3) -> 1327.9 (1434.3) MB, 22.7 / 0 ms (+ 0.3 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure].
121595 ms: Scavenge 1327.9 (1434.3) -> 1327.9 (1434.3) MB, 22.9 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
121617 ms: Scavenge 1327.9 (1434.3) -> 1327.9 (1434.3) MB, 22.0 / 0 ms [allocation failure].


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy
Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
Exited with code 134
```

When run locally with `top` filtering to the Pid of `node`, it hits about 1.4GB of memory usage, without sourcemaps it hits about 800mb.

CircleCI allow 4gb (from what I can find) of memory, I don't understand why I am getting this error (randomly).

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Please share your package.json

Comment: Just to sure, try to increase your resource class to medium+ and see what happens. I don't think it's this, but you don't lose anything to try, it will give you a hint https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#resource_class

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous open/closed/duplicate issues on github about the issue, so I'm just posting important information from the issues. May be one or more suggestions might work (I personally haven't encountered bug yet!).

1. Disable sourcemaps if you don't need them
2. Downgrade angular-cli and check if it solves your issue
3. Install and use `increase-memory-limit` package in your app
4. Increase `max_old_space_size` as specified [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618#issuecomment-296150772)

I Hope it helps!

References:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10897

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618